# confusion about conditional problem

Tags: conditional-probability

```
The TryMe smartphone company has three factories
making its phones. They are all fairly unreliable:
10% of the phones from factory 1 are defective,
20% of the phones from factory 2 are defective,
and 24% of the phones from factory 3 are 
defective. 
The factories do not produce the same numbers of
phones: factory 1 produces 1/2 of TryMe’s phones,
while factories 2 and 3 each produce 1/4.
.
(a) What is the probability that a TryMe phone
chosen at random is defective?
(b) Given that a TryMe phone is defective, what 
is the probability that it came from Factory 3?
```

Let event A = phone is defective; event B = this phone was produced by Factory 3
I want to compute P(A, B).

problem (a) is to Find **P(A)**.

Let assume factory A produces 100 phones, then 10 of them are defective.
With that being said, we have a total 100 / 50% = 200 phones. 
So, we know Factory 2 produces 10 defective phones out of a total of 50. Likewise, Factory 3 produces 12 defective phones out of a total of 50.

So, we compute P(A) = (10 + 10 + 12) / 200 = 0.16

But I have a problem with computing question 2.

Comment: I edited the line breaks in your question for legibility. And it seemed that the `/` in `1/4` was missing. Please check that I have not changed your intent.

Comment: This is a standard problem using Bayes Theorem for sets. Please look at the 'Related' Q&A's in the right-hand margin $\rightarrow.$

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

By the Law of Total Probability:
$$P(D) = \frac 12(.1) + \frac 14(.2) + \frac 14(.24).$$
By Definition of conditional probability:
$$P(F_3|D) = \frac 14(.24)/P(D).$$
I'll leave it to you to fill in gaps and state reasons for each step.

Answer (score 0):

You solved question 1 by assuming a time-frame in which company 1,2 and 3 produce [100,50,50] phones. Then you multiplied these [100,50,50] phones with the error rate of the respective companies.

With your solution (10, 10, 12) you know which fraction of all 32 defective phones is produced by which company.

You produced the answer yourself, you just needed the last final realization!